# What are the self destructs in this transaction for?

Tags: etherscan, selfdestruct, bsc

I have been using websites like [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) and [Bscscan](https://bscscan.com) for almost 2 months and recently I have found [this](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x66869eee6cdeed03e1ed4c5bb5b9a1a3125684f698584bb15a30187afd58047d) random transaction and realised that I have no idea what is going on with this self destructs... I mean I know that it is used for removing a contract from the blockchain and its also useful for saving some transactions fees but after calling self destruct the contract is gone from the blockchain and cannot be used afterwards am I right? Also why is this guy calling it that often?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice that this transaction burned 5 Chi Gastokens. Burning Chi Gastokens reduce the gas used by the transaction by self-destructing contracts that were deployed previously at a cheaper gas price. It's a way to reduce the transaction fee.

Chi are minted at a cheap gas price and are burned at a high gas price.

Read [this](https://blog.1inch.exchange/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-chi-gastoken-a1ba0ea55bf3), it explains it better than I do.

Comment: and why does the self destruction take place exactly 5 times? Also is the transaction fee displayed here already the transaction fee he payed at the end or does the safed fees get deducted afterwards?

Comment: Burning 5 Chi Tokens means self-destructing 5 contracts. The fee shown in the transaction is what the real fee paid (after the CHI reduction).